# How do I clear stuck/stale Resque workers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, redis, resque

As you can see from the attached image, I've got a couple of workers that seem to be stuck. Those processes shouldn't take longer than a couple of seconds.

[image]

I'm not sure why they won't clear or how to manually remove them.

I'm on Heroku using Resque with Redis-to-Go and HireFire to automatically scale workers.

Comment: Hi, semi-related question: how did you get the resque-web dashboard via heroku? I can't seem to figure out how to open it.

Answer (score 226, accepted):

None of these solutions worked for me, I would still see this in redis-web:

```
0 out of 10 Workers Working
```

Finally, this worked for me to clear all the workers:

```
Resque.workers.each {|w| w.unregister_worker}
```

Comment: This worked for me.  It unregistered *all* workers which was a bit annoying.  But this followed by `heroku restart` seemed to do the trick.  It now shows the correct number of workers.

Comment: This took out the workers from the web interface, but actually they still show up as processes and also "stole" jobs from the queue

Comment: If you want to unregister only the workers that are not actual processes (and perhaps processing jobs), you might want to try `Resque.workers.each {|w| matches = w.id.match(/^[^:]*:([0-9]*):[^:]*$/); pid = matches[1]; w.unregister_worker unless w.worker_pids.include?(pid.to_s)}` which will only unregister those workers which pids are not part of the known running pids.  I do not know if this works in all environment but it works good on ubuntu.  This might only work when your workers are on the same machine that you run this code on.

Comment: As an option
  Resque.workers.map &:unregister_worker

Comment: How come this doesn't include a check for whether the worker *should* be unregistered before calling `unregister_worker`? Is there a way to determine this?

Comment: Be aware that this does not get rid of workers processes.

Comment: Here's one way that *seems* to work to remove only actually appearantly-dead workers in resque 2.0.0: `Resque::Worker.all_workers_with_expired_heartbeats.each { |w| w.unregister_worker }`

Answer (score 54):

In your console:

```
queue_name = "process_numbers"
Resque.redis.del "queue:#{queue_name}"
```

Otherwise you can try to fake them as being done to remove them, with:

```
Resque::Worker.working.each {|w| w.done_working}
```

**EDIT**

A lot of people have been upvoting this answer and I feel that it's important that people try hagope's solution which unregisters workers off a queue, whereas the above code deletes queues. If you're happy to fake them, then cool.

Comment: If he does this it will delete the whole queue, he just wants to remove the stuck ones..

Comment: Small update: You now have to use Resque.redis.del instead of Resque.redis.delete

Comment: There's actually a Resque.remove_queue() method now

Answer (score 30):

You probably have the resque gem installed, so you can open the console and get current workers

```
Resque.workers
```

It returns a list of workers

```
#=> [#<Worker infusion.local:40194-0:JAVA_DYNAMIC_QUEUES,index_migrator,converter,extractor>]
```

pick the worker and `prune_dead_workers`, for example the first one

```
Resque.workers.first.prune_dead_workers
```

Comment: Actually, on second try, this didn't do anything.

Comment: This works great for clearing out resque workers who were killed off without unregistering.

Comment: This seems like the new best answer since it doesn't unregister all of them.  Shouldn't prune_dead_workers be a class method?  But in any event, great solution! Thanks.

Comment: That's definitely the solution for killed -9 workers. The only thing i would add is that you need to do that on same server where you killed with -9.

Comment: Do it to all of them at once: Resque.workers.each(&:prune_dead_workers)

Comment: Is there anything to add in JAVA for workers not to get into this state?

Answer (score 27):

Adding to answer by hagope, I wanted to be able to only unregister workers that had been running for a certain amount of time. The code below will only unregister workers running for over 300 seconds (5 minutes).

```
Resque.workers.each {|w| w.unregister_worker if w.processing['run_at'] && Time.now - w.processing['run_at'].to_time > 300}
```

I have an ongoing collection of Resque related Rake tasks that I have also added this to: https://gist.github.com/ewherrmann/8809350

Comment: Points for showing how to access the job start time via processing['run_at']. I've seen other solutions that are using the .started method, but this actually returns the time the *worker* was started, not the job, which is the wrong approach for clearing stuck workers. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

Run this command wherever you ran the command to start the server

```
$ ps -e -o pid,command | grep [r]esque
```

you should see something like this:

```
92102 resque: Processing ProcessNumbers since 1253142769
```

Make note of the PID (process id) in my example it is **92102**

Then you can quit the process 1 of 2 ways.

- Gracefully use `QUIT 92102`
- Forcefully use `TERM 92102`

*** I'm not sure of the syntax it's either `QUIT 92102` or `QUIT -92102`

Let me know if you have any trouble.

Comment: In the Linux console:
kill -SIGQUIT 92102

Answer (score 7):

I just did:

```
% rails c production
irb(main):001:0>Resque.workers
```

Got the list of workers.

```
irb(main):002:0>Resque.remove_worker(Resque.workers[n].id)
```

... where n is the zero based index of the unwanted worker.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem that Redis saved the DB to disk that included invalid (non running) workers. Each time Redis/resque was started they appeared.

Fix this using:

```
Resque::Worker.working.each {|w| w.done_working}
Resque.redis.save # Save the DB to disk without ANY workers
```

Make sure you restart Redis and your Resque workers.

Answer (score 2):

Started working on https://github.com/shaiguitar/resque_stuck_queue/ recently. It's not a solution to how to fix stuck workers but it addresses the issue of resque hanging/being stuck, so I figured it could be helpful for people on this thread. From README:

"If resque doesn't run jobs within a certain timeframe, it will trigger a pre-defined handler of your choice. You can use this to send an email, pager duty, add more resque workers, restart resque, send you a txt...whatever suits you."

Been used in production and works pretty well for me thus far.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how you can purge them from Redis by hostname. This happens to me when I decommission a server and workers do not exit gracefully.

```
Resque.workers.each { |w| w.unregister_worker if w.id.start_with?(hostname) }
```

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this issue and started down the path of implementing a lot of the suggestions here. However, I discovered the root cause that was creating this issue was that I was [using the gem redis-rb 3.3.0](https://github.com/resque/resque/issues/1452). Downgrading to redis-rb 3.2.2 prevented these workers from getting stuck in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

I've cleared them out from redis-cli directly. Luckily redistogo.com allows access from environments outside heroku.
Get dead worker ID from the list. Mine was

```
55ba6f3b-9287-4f81-987a-4e8ae7f51210:2
```

Run this command in redis directly.

```
del "resque:worker:55ba6f3b-9287-4f81-987a-4e8ae7f51210:2:*"
```

You can monitor redis db to see what it's doing behind the scenes.

```
redis xxx.redistogo.com> MONITOR
OK
1380274567.540613 "MONITOR"
1380274568.345198 "incrby" "resque:stat:processed" "1"
1380274568.346898 "incrby" "resque:stat:processed:c65c8e2b-555a-4a57-aaa6-477b27d6452d:2:*" "1"
1380274568.346920 "del" "resque:worker:c65c8e2b-555a-4a57-aaa6-477b27d6452d:2:*"
1380274568.348803 "smembers" "resque:queues"
```

Second last line deletes the worker.

Comment: Not a good idea. This won't call unregister hooks in Resque, not calling failure and possible clean up code people may have.

Comment: This was useful with resque 2 years ago when it was showing stuck jobs that were impossible to delete using the interface and there was no clean way to do it in rails

Answer (score 1):

In resque 2.0.0, here's one way that *seems* to work to remove only actually appearantly-dead workers in resque 2.0.0:

```rb
Resque::Worker.all_workers_with_expired_heartbeats.each { |w| w.unregister_worker }
```

I am not an expert in what's going, it's possible there's a better way to do this or that this will have problems.  I'm just trying to figure this out too.

This seems to remove workers that haven't sent a "heartbeat" in much longer than expected from the *resque worker list*.

If the phantom worker was in a "running" state, then a new entry in the "failed" job queue will be created corresponding to phantom job.

Answer (score 0):

I had stuck/stale resque workers here too, or should I say 'jobs', because the worker is actually still there and running fine, it's the forked process that is stuck.

I chose the brutal solution of killing the forked process "Processing" since more than 5min, via a bash script, then the worker just spawn the next in queue, and everything keeps on going

have a look at my script here: https://gist.github.com/jobwat/5712437

Answer (score 0):

If you are using newer versions of Resque, you'll need to use the following command as the internal APIs have changed...

```
Resque::WorkerRegistry.working.each {|work| Resque::WorkerRegistry.remove(work.id)}
```

Answer (score 0):

This avoids the problem as long as you have a resque version newer than 1.26.0:

```
resque: env QUEUE=foo TERM_CHILD=1 bundle exec rake resque:work
```

Keep in mind that it does not let the currently running job finish.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Docker, you can also use this command:

`<id>` is the worker id.

```
docker stop <id>

docker start <id>
```