# Why can I see so many workers at Heroku? How do I restrict access to other workers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, redis, redislabs

When I access resque-web on my Rails-app running at Heroku, I can see more than 40 workers:
[image]

I have only 1 resque worker connected to my Heroku account. This worker processes all my queues:

```
resque: env TERM_CHILD=1 COUNT=1 QUEUE=* bundle exec rake resque:workers
```

Is there a way I can restrict other peoples workers to interfere with my queue?
I'm using the [Redislab](http://redislabs.com/) adon from Heroku.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your Redis Cloud instance is password-protected, it is unlikely that these are other peoples' workers. I'd venture a guess that they are simply stale (i.e. dead) workers.

Since resque workers register and keep their state in Redis, it is not uncommon that when a worker dies it's state information is kept in Redis. [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7416318/how-do-i-clear-stuck-stale-resque-workers) provided more pointers on how to deal with the situation.