# RubyOnRails How to Kill Stuck/Stale Resque Workers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resque, resque-scheduler

Unfortunately, one job runs every hour instead of once a day.

Frequent deployment is not possible because of Traffic.

Looking for some script to KILL the specific resque process. For reference:

[image]

Want to KILL the First Two Jobs because they are running for the last 4 hours.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I clear stuck/stale Resque workers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7416318/how-do-i-clear-stuck-stale-resque-workers)

Comment: In the above URL, answers delete the complete queue workers. I want to kill a specific process using process id.